# Buttons are overproportionally big on mobile phone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I've got the following code on my website

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2 option">
    <button id='yes' type='submit' class='btn btn-success btn-block' name='yes' onclick="nextThesis('a')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Zustimmung</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 option">
    <button id='neutral' type='submit' class='btn btn-warning btn-block' name='neutral' onclick="nextThesis('b')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tree-deciduous"></span> Neutral</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 option">
    <button id='no' type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-block' name='no' onclick="nextThesis('c')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> Ablehnung</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 option">
    <button id='skip' type='submit' class='btn btn-default btn-block' name='skip' onclick="nextThesis('d')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Überspringen</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Whenever the website is displayed in a desktop browser the buttons size fits to the size of the other elements. On mobile phone however, the buttons unproportionally huge compared to all the other elements.

How can this be resolved?

Best Regards,

Philipp

Comment: Your buttons are small on mobile devices for me.

Comment: You column markup looks a little strange to me. `<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 option">`. Normally you would not define all the breakpoints to have the same number of columns. You have 6 columns for the row at each breakpoint. Why? Not sure if that's impacting the size of the buttons or not. This should be enough `<div class="col-xs-2">` Also, what's the `option` class doing?